# SQL exclude rows based on value in another row

Tags: sql

I am trying to exclude rows where a value exists in another row.

```
select * from TABLE1

ROW SEQ VALUE
1   1   HIGH
1   2   HIGH
1   3   LOW
1   4   HIGH
2   1   MED
2   2   HIGH
2   3   HIGH
2   4   LOW
2   5   HIGH
2   6   HIGH
```

All the data is coming from the same table what I am trying to do is exclude the rows where VALUE = 'LOW' and all previous rows where SEQ <= the row with the value = 'LOW'. This is my desired result:

```
 ROW SEQ VALUE
1   4   HIGH
2   5   HIGH
2   6   HIGH
```

Here's work in progress but it's only excluding the one row

```
select * from TABLE1
where not exists(select VALUE from TABLE1 
where ROW = ROW and VALUE = 'LOW' and SEQ <= SEQ)
```

I need to write it into the where cause as the select is hard coded. I am lost any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your description and your sample data don't seem to match.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1
left outer join (
    select row, max(seq) as seq
    from table1
    where value = 'low'
    group by row
) lows on lows.row = table1.row
where lows.row is null
   or table1.seq > lows.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aliasing the tables. I'm surprised you are getting any results from this query as you don't have aliases at all.

```
select * 
from TABLE1 As t0
where not exists(
    select VALUE 
    from TABLE1 As t1
    where t0.ROW = t1.ROW 
    and t1.VALUE = 'LOW' 
    and t0.SEQ <= t1.SEQ
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Zohar sorry I was aliasing but tried to simplify the query for an example. I was NOT however aliasing the table in the not exists clause. Thank you this did the trick!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

For the results you mention, you seem to want the rows after the last "low".  One method is:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.seq > (select max(t2.seq) from table1 tt1 where tt1.row = t1.row and tt1.value = 'LOW');
```

(Note:  This requires a "low" row.  If there could be no "low" rows and you want all rows returned, that is easily added to the query.)

Or, similarly, using `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1 
                  where tt1.row = t1.row and
                        tt1.seq > t.seq and
                        tt1.value = 'LOW'
                 );
```

This might be the most direct translation of your question.

However, I would more likely use window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             max(case when t1.value = 'low' then seqnum end) over (partition by row) as max_low_seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum > max_low_seqnum;
```

You might want to add `or max_low_seqnum is null` to return all rows if there are no "low" rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function with a cumulative approach  :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(case when value = 'LOW' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by row order by seq) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 and value <> 'LOW';
```